# Excel Applescript to select column

Tags: excel, applescript

I'm trying to make an excel (v16.4) applescript that deletes the first few rows then moves to the last column, which will have the heading "Notes", and copies that text into column F.

The first part is working fine but I can't get it to select the column for me. The problem I've been having is that the "Notes" column is in a different spot in each file. I can get to the Notes column but nothing I've tried gets excel to select the whole column from this point, I just get the error "The object you are trying to access does not exist". I've copied my last 2  applescripts for this bit below; I've tried a few options and had no luck.

VERSION 1

```
-- find "Notes" column
            set lastRow to count of rows of used range of active sheet
            set theEnd to get end range "A1" direction toward the right
            select theEnd
            set x to (get column entry index of the active cell)
            select column x
```

VERSION 2

```
    --Find "Notes" column
            set findNotes to "Notes"
            set searchRange to range ("A1:AN1")
            set foundColumn to find searchRange what findNotes with match case
            goto reference foundColumn

    --Duplicate Column
            set addr to get address (column 1 of selection)
            set addr to text 2 thru 2 of addr
            -- e.g range $H:$H"
            set myWantedRange to "$" & addr & ":$" & addr
            set src to range myWantedRange of sheet 1 of workbook "Workbook1"
            set dst to range column 6 of sheet 1 of workbook "Workbook1"

            copy range src destination dst
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Basically, it gets the last column of the used range and checks to see if its first cell is 'Notes'. If it is, then it copies the values of the column's cells, and then puts them into the corresponding cells of the used range's column 6. Everything is bounded by the used range.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet 1 of workbook 1
        with timeout of 20 seconds
            
            set cour to columns of used range
            
            set lCol to last item of cour
            set fCol to item 6 of cour
            
            if value of cell 1 of lCol is "Notes" then
                
                set lcv to value of lCol
                set value of fCol to lcv
                
            end if
        end timeout
    end tell
end tell
```

`cour` is a limited list of columns. Its last column (lCol) will be referenced this way:

```
column "$J$1:$J$30" of application "Microsoft Excel"
```

Then it's just a matter of setting column F's values. I'm using Excel 2011 but it shouldn't be an issue here. The timeout lines are just there to halt proceedings in case you try and work with an entire column.

I don't think you need to select anything but if you wanted to select either of the columns (within used range), just use one of these:

```
select fcol
select lcol
select column "$J$1:$J$30"
```